# How to limit possible property values in type derived from another type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have existing type

```
interface ColDef {
   field: string;
   // some other properties
}
```

and I would like to infer new type with the same properties, but restring field property to:

```
field: 'ID' | 'Name' | 'SomeOtherProps'
```

or alternatively

```
field: keyof Customer
```

Is it possible to infer a new type from existing type and change type of one or more properties?

Comment: Share some details about `Customer`. I will update my answer with possibilities

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "infer".  You can make `interface RestrictedColDef extends ColDef { field: keyof Customer }` and it should work (assuming `keyof Customer` is assignable to `string` and doesn't include `number` or `symbol` values).

Answer (score 1):

Just extend the base type and override property definition:

```
interface MyColDef extends ColDef {
  field: 'ID' | 'Name'
}

let myCol: MyColDef = {
  field: 'blabla' //compiler error
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom type using `type` to restrict the property values.

```js
type Field = "ID" | "Name" | "SomeOtherProps"

interface ColDef {
   field: Field;
}
```

In the above code `field` will only accepts `"ID", "Name", "SomeOtherProps"`

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-71hx7a)

Comment: Yeah, but that is not what I asked. I cannot change ColDef type, but instead I need to create new type derived from it

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by infer.

Comment: By infer I mean any approach that would keep the properties from the base class. Inheritance is one of them